# Can't open a project file, keeps showing file existed while it doesn't

Tags: flutter

There is this flutter project file that I want to import, it's probably an old project, when I try importing it I get this error message of an existing file but, there is none.

I also deleted .idea folder but still showing the same error message "Error adding module to project: Module already exists: aapt".
I freshly install android studio on a new PC and still shows the same error.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to do ```flutter pub get``` and ```flutter upgrade```?

Comment: can't do anything. I get the error shortly after clicking finish to complete the import

Comment: Did you tried to import another project? Maybe it's fault of project not android studio code.

Comment: other projects are import correctly but, this specific project isn't

Comment: Did you called your app aapt?

Comment: i don't think so, i just import projects as i normally do, shortly after verifying files i get the error so, am not sure